# Reading and storing XML data in arrays

Tags: python, xml

Sorry if this question is stupid but I can't seem to get my way through it. I have a .xml file which looks like:

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName="bayesian" Count="1342" ExcerptPostId="20258" WikiPostId="20257" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="prior" Count="168" ExcerptPostId="62158" WikiPostId="62157" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="elicitation" Count="6" />
  <row Id="4" TagName="normality" Count="191" ExcerptPostId="67815" WikiPostId="67814" />
  <row Id="5" TagName="open-source" Count="13" />
  <row Id="6" TagName="distributions" Count="1880" ExcerptPostId="8046" WikiPostId="8045" />
  <row Id="9" TagName="machine-learning" Count="2564" ExcerptPostId="9066" WikiPostId="9065" />
  <row Id="10" TagName="dataset" Count="514" ExcerptPostId="20490" WikiPostId="20489" />
  <row Id="11" TagName="sample" Count="219" ExcerptPostId="28276" WikiPostId="28275" />
  <row Id="12" TagName="population" Count="120" ExcerptPostId="69287" WikiPostId="69286" />
  <row Id="15" TagName="measurement" Count="97" ExcerptPostId="66319" WikiPostId="66318" />
  <row Id="16" TagName="scales" Count="157" />
```

---

All I need to do is to read this .xml file and store the data in arrays so that I can analyze that. I do the following steps;

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Tags.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print root
<Element 'tags' at 0x10365d810>
In [37]: root.attrib
Out[37]: {}

root.getchildren
Out[38]: <bound method Element.getchildren of <Element 'tags' at 0x10365d810>>

In [39]: root.getiterator
Out[39]: <bound method Element.getiterator of <Element 'tags' at 0x10365d810>>

In [40]: root.items
Out[40]: <bound method Element.items of <Element 'tags' at 0x10365d810>>

In [41]: root.keys
Out[41]: <bound method Element.keys of <Element 'tags' at 0x10365d810>>
```

Somehow, I can't find the step to oread the columns.
Thanks for help, I am very new with Python and XML
Prakash

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName="bayesian" Count="1342" ExcerptPostId="20258" WikiPostId="20257" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="prior" Count="168" ExcerptPostId="62158" WikiPostId="62157" />
  <row Id="3" TagName="elicitation" Count="6" />
  <row Id="4" TagName="normality" Count="191" ExcerptPostId="67815"

Comment: Update the post with the xml and how you want the list to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `root` to get the children. Each child has a `dict` member called `attrib`. In your XML, the `.attrib` member will contain all of the data you need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Tags.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


tags = {tag.attrib['TagName']:tag.attrib for tag in root}

print tags['bayesian']['WikiPostId']
print tags['scales']['Count']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`root.getchildren`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren) is a function , you should call it to get the childrens of the root node (as - `root.getchildren()` ), though they have been deprecated since Python 2.7 .

You should rather iterate over the root and then store the attributes of the children of root in a list, example -

```
listofelems = []
for item in root:
    listofelems.append(item.attrib)
print(listofelems)
```